# GAE+PHP: How to override MySQL credentials for development environment on windows?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

Followed all steps here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/ but no matter what I do, I cannot override `MYSQL_*` env variables on **Windows**.

Tried:

- `set "MYSQL_PASSWORD=PASS"` in command prompt
- `dev_appserver.py --mysql_password pass`
- `dev_appserver.py --mysql_password=pass`

Nothing works. `getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')` always returns value declared in `app.yaml`.

Comment: Are you using/supporting windows in production? If not I strongly advise against developing on it. You end up spending time on os spesific issues that are irrelevant, at the same time you might add code that will work in dev but not prod. Using a virtual dev environment means the entire team can develop on the exact same machine. https://box.scotch.io/ is an easy start, for serious projects I suggest setting up a dev environment that properly reflects production

Comment: I'm deploying to App Engine, not Compute Engine. I don't have any access to environment there. Overall, I just need to get dev_appserver.py to run properly, the way google means it to.